# Quick search in android application

Tags: android, search, quick-search

I am making an android application that needs to display a simple quick search, but to do this i need to change the:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

To:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

But once I do, the application doesn't find a launcher activity, how can i fix this? This is the code that i am using:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mysoftwaremobileapps.School"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SchoolActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".GoogleActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".WikipediaActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".ProjectsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".NotesActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchFunction" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter android:label="ACTION_SEARCH"></intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason for a `LAUNCHER` to exist in a [searchable activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).

The point of a searchable activity is that after a search is triggered by the user, your activity then [receives](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#ReceivingTheQuery) the search query, [searches](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#SearchingYourData) your datastore, and finally [presents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#PresentingTheResults) the results.

Now if you wanted a *separate* activity that does something related to your datastore, for example input or import data, then by all means go ahead and create another activity and assign `LAUNCHER` to that activity. The searchable activity isn't meant to be a `LAUNCHER` activity.

Comment: But if i dont change it, it doesn't happen anything when i press search

Comment: And how do i get the text that the user entered into the search field into a string?

Comment: @user1183066 Is your search activity able to receive, search and present the results (see the examples above)? It will _only_ be able to return results after you get that working. Please go through the examples I linked to and get a basic search application going before expanding into a WebView.